# PostgreSQL replication not working after base backup

Tags: postgresql, replication, linux, postgresql-9.4, master-slave-replication

Last week we had an incident with our master PostgreSQL server instance which got totally thrashed so, we had to switch to our slave as our one and only DB instance. After the initial chaos was controlled, we tried to create a new slave replica from scratch, according to instructions left by our DB provider who actually set up the first master-slave replica, but just yesterday I realized that the slave wasn't really replicating at all and, only has the contents of the initial base backup, so we have no redundancy right now in case of a new disaster!

On `recovery.conf` we have:

```
standby_mode = on
primary_conninfo = 'host=10.1.1.65 port=5432 user=replicador password=XXXXXXXX'
```

In `/var/lib/postgresql.log` (master) there are several messages like this:

```
2017-03-17 12:21:57 UTC [1969-1] replicador@[unknown] ERROR:  requested WAL segment 0000000100000B280000003A has already been removed
```

And in the replica's log file, many messages like:

```
2017-03-22 13:22:32 UTC [2827-1] LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at B28/3A000000 on timeline 1
2017-03-22 13:22:32 UTC [2827-2] FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 0000000100000B280000003A has already been removed
```

Seems like the process wasn't fast enough to keep the master's pace. What parameters should I check/raise? Can I actually re-sync, or am I lost and once we'll have to do it all over again?

What could be missing? What additional info should I provide?

Environment:

```
select version()
PostgreSQL 9.4.9 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2, 64-bit

lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.6 (jessie)
Release:    8.6
Codename:   jessie

uname -a
Linux ip-10-1-0-139 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Please check your server logs in master and replica. With Debian-packaged postgreSQL, they're inside `/var/log/postgresql`.

Comment: Thanks @DanielVérité for pointing an obvious search location, which actually led to suspicious messages, as I've added to the question above

Comment: As it sounds, you have to turn WAL archiving on, to prevent removal of the segments.

Comment: @dezso Definitely sounds like a great approach, and in our case that we are working in AWS I guess S3 could be a suitable storage for such archive. Now arises another question: what to do with those files and, how to used to recreate a slave or help recovering from this question's describe scenario

Comment: Yes, S3 is a good place.  Make it writable from both instances (for preparing a failover).  Archive the segments by setting `archive_command`, and let the slave consume these via `restore_command`.  Finally, `archive_cleanup_command` will help removing those that are already replayed, thus no longer needed.  You could also look into https://github.com/wal-e/wal-e, or for a complete HA solution https://github.com/zalando/spilo (developed by the colleagues on the other side of my desk).

Comment: @dezso Ok, I think I get it, thanks a lot. Just another question. By using this method our current replication method should be replaced by this one, or is this one an add-on?

Answer (score 1):

Your base backup looks old as current master (earlier slave) must be on timeline greater than 1 after getting promoted as master but your slave is on still timeline 1.
You can either create a new slave from scratch after taking a new base backup from new master.
Or you can try timeline switch in the current non replicating slave (not sure about it) refer it here http://paquier.xyz/postgresql-2/postgres-9-3-feature-highlight-timeline-switch-of-slave-node-without-archives/

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on the "timeline" reference? I'm not aware of such concept

Comment: You can refer about timelines here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-TIMELINES

Comment: Try adding recovery_target_timeline='latest' in slaves' recovery.conf and restart your slave.It should automatically move the slave on latest timeline

Comment: Great concept the timelines!!