# Post Mortem Analysis: PostgreSQL replication failed

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.4, data-synchronization, master-slave-replication

We have a PostgreSQL 9.4.9 production server which was replicating to a slave instance, but today I discovered that the instance is out of sync!

The obvious actions would be to recreate the slave, [setup metrics](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/157482/metrics-for-monitoring-master-slave-replication) and proper alarms for the replication activity, so we can effectively monitor the sync status between master and slave nodes.

But, as the sync failed, I'd like to first diagnose the problem and try to identify the root cause of it, as this would be the [second time](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167859/postgresql-replication-not-working-after-base-backup) this happens in about 6 months.

**Question**: How to diagnose what failed in the replication process so it can be done in a better way this time?

Version specifics:

```
PostgreSQL 9.4.9 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2, 64-bit
```

From slave node, at `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.4-main.log` I can see:

```
2017-07-18 19:43:55 UTC [12816-1] LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 125D/68000000 on timeline 1
2017-07-18 19:43:55 UTC [12816-2] FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010000125D00000068 has already been removed

2017-07-18 19:44:00 UTC [12817-1] LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 125D/68000000 on timeline 1
2017-07-18 19:44:00 UTC [12817-2] FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010000125D00000068 has already been removed

2017-07-18 19:44:05 UTC [12821-1] LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 125D/68000000 on timeline 1
2017-07-18 19:44:05 UTC [12821-2] FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010000125D00000068 has already been removed

2017-07-18 19:44:10 UTC [12825-1] LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 125D/68000000 on timeline 1
2017-07-18 19:44:10 UTC [12825-2] FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010000125D00000068 has already been removed

2017-07-18 19:44:15 UTC [12826-1] LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 125D/68000000 on timeline 1
2017-07-18 19:44:15 UTC [12826-2] FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010000125D00000068 has already been removed
```

**New Question**: How can I see backward on where the actual problem appeared?

Master `postgresql.conf`: https://pastebin.com/NJX5ku6m

Slave `postgresql.conf`: https://pastebin.com/CUZcyazC

Slave `recovery.conf`:

```
standby_mode = on
primary_conninfo = 'host=10.1.1.65 port=5432 user=replicador password=replicador'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on this I'd say you didn't have enough `wal_keep_segments` on the master, weren't using a replication slot, and either had `hot_standby_feedback` off or had the connection drop for long enough for the master to remove needed WAL.

And you are presumably not using WAL archiving (`archive_command` on master, `restore_command` on replica) as fallback.

So the master removed transaction logs the standby needed.

You'll need to re-create the standby. Then either:

- Set the standby to use a replication slot and enable `hot_standby_feedback`; or
- enable `archive_command` and `restore_command`

Comment: We are not "masters" on replication, so I've added the full config files within the question body. But I guess we are (were) using replication slots, but we still don't really know when it failed and certainly not why

Comment: @GonzaloVasquez I don't see a replication slot specified in `recovery.conf` so there's no reason to think you were. It's exactly as I expected - no `restore_command`, no replication slot. You were relying on `wal_keep_segments` for resource retention and your replica got too far behind, sot he master removed needed resources. Exactly what's expected. No `hot_standby_feedback` was set on the replica to make sure it kept more if it got busy. Even if it had been enabled the master might still remove WALs the replica(s) need if the replicas disconnect.

Comment: @GonzaloVasquez So either use WAL archiving as a fallback, or use a replication slot. If you use a replication slot understand that you MUST monitor pg_xlog space on the master and replication progress or the master WILL run out of disk and crash if the replica gets too far behind.

Comment: great comments, I guess that'll do it. I'll provide feedback if in need. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

First thing: look at the logs. You will find warnings, error, fatal, and panic messages.

You can find where your logs are in your `postgresql.conf` file.

Look for the `logging_collector` setting, if it's `on`, you will find your server logs in the directory specified in the `log_directory` setting.

If `logging_collector` is set to `off`, look at the `log_destination` setting. If it's `syslog` you need to look at your syslog settings to find where your logs are. 
If it's `stderr` you might find something under `/proc/<PID>/fd/2` where `<PID>` is the PID of your running PostgreSQL server.

You might find this [page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html) of documentation usefull.

Comment: `#logging_collector = off`  and   `#log_destination = 'stderr'` both on master and slave instances